# pass value to another page from jquery in post method

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to know what is `.result`,`data`:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: `.result` is the class name of a html container (probably a div) and `data` contains the response from the page you requested.

Answer (score 1):

In `Jquery` stand point `.result` is a `class` `attribute` value. like

```
<p class="result"></p> // example tag
```

fetch this `tag` in `jquery` by using `$(".result")` //p tag reference

and `data` is a `response` from `back end` when you `post` the `data` using `$.post method.`

so, here you are placing the responce `data` what you got from server  inside a `p` tag that's it .....

Answer (score 0):

Heres a debugging tip, echo the data in an alert first.

$.post("ajax/test.html",function(data){alert(data);});

Try that and tell us what it kicks out. It should return the HTML of test.html

Comment: Don't debug in alerts. It will often throw a lot of alerts which makes you have to click the checkbox to never show alerts again. Turning that on again is a pain in the ass. When you want to debug, use `Console.log?()`! Not just because of that, but also because it accepts any kind of variable/object/whatever.

Comment: Never once had a problem using alerts

Comment: You will when you start debugging loops ;-) I also think the console is much more readable. And it doesn't block the page for doing other stuff.

Comment: True, never used it in a loop though.